# JQGRID : changing the icon class based on popup ok button

Tags: jqgrid

I am using JqGrid, the second column has lot of icons which open up a Popup. When user click ok button in the popup, i need to change the class for icon in the second column of that particular row in jqgrid.

I am using tableToGrid() for building JqGrid.

We have dependencies for using tableToGrid mtd.

Updated for Code ::

```
var options = {
            datatype:'local',
            width:"1360",
            height: "100%",
            shrinkToFit: false,
            rownumbers: false,
            gridview: true,
            multiSort: true,
            sortname: "Id",
            sortorder: "asc",
            viewrecords: true,
            loadui: true,
            loadonce: true,
            multiselect:false,
            rowNum : 10000,
            deepempty : true,
            //loadComplete: function() { },
            //colName: [checkboxHeader,dragHandle,'Description', 'Media', 'Source Type', 'Source', 'Auto Firm', 'Auto Firm Period','', '', '', '', '', '', ''],
            colName: [checkboxHeader,'Title','Fin Prod ID', 'Product Type', 'Title Tags', 'Date Type', 'Territory','Language', 'Release Date', 'Rel Date Status', 'Feed Date', 'Feed Date Status', 'Manual Date', 
                      'Temp/Perm','Projected Date','Rel Date Tags','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','','',''],// count is 33
            colModel: [{name: 'rdr_checkboxHeader',editable: false, width:30, align:'center', sortable:false, formatter:that.rowSelectorFormatter},
                       {name: 'rdr_icon',editable: false, sortable:false, formatter:that.iconFormatter},
                       {name: 'rdr_titleName',editable: false, width:190,sortable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_fnnclPrdctId', editable: true, width:95,  sortable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_productType', editable: false, width:95, sortable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_titleTags', editable: false, width:90, sortable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_dateType', editable: false, width:70, /*align:'center',*/ sortable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_territory', editable: false, width:170, sortable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_language', width:90, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_releaseDate', width:90, editable:false, /*formatter:that.releaseDateFormatter,formatoptions:{newformat:'dd-M-yy'},*/ sorttype: "date",sortable:true },
                       {name: 'rdr_relDateStatus', width:90, editable:false,formatter:that.relDateStatusFormatter},
                       {name: 'rdr_feedDate', width:90, editable:false,},
                       {name: 'rdr_feedDateStatus', width:90, editable:true},
                       {name: 'rdr_manualDate', width:90, editable:false,formatter:that.manualDateFormatter},
                       {name: 'rdr_tempPerm', width:90, editable:true, formatter:that.tempPermFormatter},
                       {name: 'rdr_projectedDate', width:90, editable:false/*,formatter:that.projectedDateFormatter*/},
                       {name: 'rdr_relDateTags', width:90, editable:true,formatter:that.redDateTagFormatter},

                       {name: 'rdr_createDate', hidden:true, editable:false, key:true},
                       {name: 'rdr_updateDate', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_createName', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_updateName', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_releaseDateId', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_comments', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_productId', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_releaseDateGuidelineId', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_dateSourceId', hidden:true, editable:false},

                       {name: 'rdr_productVersionId', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_admissions', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_boxOfficeAmountLc', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_boxOfficeAmountUsd', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_compareString', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_versionId', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_intlPrdTypeId', hidden:true, editable:false},
                       {name: 'rdr_relaseDateTags', hidden:true, editable:false},]
    };
    tableToGrid("#gridId", options);
```

Formatter look like this

`this.iconFormatter = function(cellvalue, options, rowObject){
        var comments  = "";
        var commentClass = "icon-comment-alt";
        var releaseDateId = "";
        if(rowObject){
            comments = rowObject.rdr_comments;
            releaseDateId = rowObject.rdr_releaseDateId;
        }
        var text = "";/*"<td nowrap>"*/;
        if(comments.trim() != '')
            commentClass = 'icon-comment';
        text += '<a href="#" class="bootbox-regular btn btn-white-pad24"> <i class="'+commentClass+'" id= "'+releaseDateId+'"_comments"   onclick="relaseDateResultProcessorObject.doOpenComments(this);"></i> </a><span class="hide commentStarClass"></span>';
//      text += '<input type="hidden" value="" id="" name="comments"/>';
        text += '<a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-white btn-white-pad24" title="Date Guide" id= "'+releaseDateId+'"_guideline" onclick="relaseDateResultProcessorObject.doCallDateGuidePopUp(this)"> <i class="icon-calendar blue"></i></a>';
        text += '<a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-white btn-white-pad24" title="History"> <i class="icon icon-fast-backward orange" onclick="relaseDateResultProcessorObject.doAjaxHistory('+releaseDateId+');"></i></a>';
        text += '<a href="#" role="button" data-toggle="modal" class="btn btn-white btn-white-pad24" title="Affected Windows"> <i class="icon icon-qrcode green" id= "'+releaseDateId+'"_affectedWindow" onclick="relaseDateResultProcessorObject.doCallAffectedWindowsPopUp(this)"></i></a>    ';
        return text;
    };`

If i click on any one of the icon, it will open a popup and when user click 'ok' then we need to change the class associated to that icon.

Hope it will make all of you to understand.

Comment: `tableToGrid` is typically not good way to create and to fill jqGrid. In avy way you should append the text of your question with JavaScript/HTML code which shows what you do exactly.

Comment: Hi Oleg, Waiting for your reply...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While opening the popup we should hold the id of the icon and update accordingly.

I figure it out like below

If i am opening an icon which has 'testId' id, hold this id in variable like `var x = 'testId'`and when user click on 'OK' button, update the object using code .`$('#'+x).addClass('commentExist');`